# Notification on multiple android phones using GCM and web services + database data

Tags: c#, php, android, sql-server, notifications

I am developing an app for selling of products, but I am stuck up in a place where I am not understanding how to give notifications to android phone from database change(insert or update on that table) for new products availble and  offers like discounts, schemes etc. 

I followed androidhive.com and javapapers.com for the GCM push notifications concept and it is sort of clear:

PHP or C# or Java web service

MySQL or SQLServer Database

GCM

Android phone

The statement for my problem would be "App should receive push notifications for new products, and offers and discounts given by the person-in-charge for it"
My assumption for this problem is:
The "offers and discounts" would be "inserted" to a table(tbl_products) in the database and same goes for new products, "inserted" into a table(tbl_offers) in the database.
As soon as that "insertion" is done, the web service (php and c#), which I don't know how it should know, but gets to know about the change and informs GCM, and GCM sends the notification to the respective users.

The logic behind this is not familiar to me. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would help me with the logic and point me in the right direction of the coding for Android and web service. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been there ,done that! The way you should to proceed is:-

1. Create your website backend, a web service connected to a database(You need to use and know SQL for this part). Define your database accordingly. PHP is the easiest way to get started. Look at the GCM backend tutorials on Google.
2. Create your mobile application which has google play services enabled to use GCM. Implement GCM in your android app following the tutorial at the [Official Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html). You need to create an XMPP or RESTful service to communicate with your server. Your server needs to support [XMPP](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) to communicate better with Google. [HTTP](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html)(GET/POST/PUT) is a dirty alternative  to get working when you do not have a VPS setup for languages like Java(Most hosting companies allow only PHP,HTML,JavaScript etc on shared hosting).Depending on your scale of operation you may have to rent a Virtual Private Server(VPS) for your web service.
3. Create a private backend application(can be web or a desktop application) to upload your offers and so on. Examples on [www.androhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
4. Make sure you got steps 1,2,3 correct.
5. Test your mobile application.

The idea can be pictorially represented as :-
[image: GCM Architecture]

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying so quick. I am sort of clear on the first part where multicast is done using MySQL and PHP. What is remaining is, on the "INSERT" or "UPDATE" of that table (containing products and offer:discounts,schemes ) how to use web service to check for that change in database and use that change to send.

Comment: You will need to learn SQL for interacting with a database in a web service. I suggest that you start here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ Also remember to upvote answers if they helped you!

Comment: Thanks buddy. Researched a bit more and found out how to send notifications using both web services, PHP and C# with database MySQL and SQL-Server respectively. :)